# update dynamic name table with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I was doing some exercises and one of them was to update a table record with a stored procedure that asks the ID of the record, the column name and the value of which that record is going to have in that column after I update.

This is my stored procedure:

```
create proc UpdateDynamically

(
@ProdID int,
@Parameter varchar(50),
@Value varchar(50)
)
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(max);

set @sql = 'update Products set ' + QUOTENAME(@Parameter) + ' = ' + @Value + ' where ProductID = ' + CONVERT(int, @ProdID)

exec(@sql)
end
```

This is my c# code:

```
protected void btnAtualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            #region UPDATE
            string aux = ddlNome.SelectedItem.Text;
            string id = aux.Substring(0, aux.IndexOf('-'));
            SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand();
            SqlParameter ProdID = new SqlParameter("@ProdID", Convert.ToInt32(id));
            SqlParameter Value = new SqlParameter("@Value", txtValor.Text);
            SqlParameter Parameter = new SqlParameter("@Parameter", ddlCampo.SelectedItem.Text);
            comm1 = new SqlCommand("update_dynamically", con);
            comm1.Parameters.Add(ProdID);
            comm1.Parameters.Add(Value);
            comm1.Parameters.Add(Parameter);
            comm1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            #endregion
            Response.Redirect("WebForm.aspx");
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        { Response.Write(sqlex.Message); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Response.Write(ex.Message); }
        finally
        { con.Close(); }
    }
```

When I run the code it doesn't give any error but the record doesn't update and when I try to "hard code" the values in SQL Server it gives this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateDynamically,
>
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'update Products set [ProductName] = Helium where ProductID = ' to data type int.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2017. I could really use some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use `sp_executesql` and pass in parameters where you can:

```
create procedute UpdateDynamically (
    @ProdID int,
    @Parameter varchar(50),
    @Value varchar(50)
) as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);

    set @sql = N'
update Products
    set @Parameter = @Value where ProductID = @ProdID
';

    set @sql = replace(@sql, '@Parameter', @Parameter);

    exec sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@value varchar(50), @ProdID int',
                       @value=@value, @ProdID=@ProdID

end;
```

You cannot pass `@Parameter` as a parameter, because that is not allowed for identifiers, only for literal values.

Your stored procedure code is failing because `@ProdID` is an integer, so `+` is interpreted as addition rather than string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you now it is working fine. Thank you very much.